# Mock database object which is called in private method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

i've started to get my hands on mocking frameworks because I want to write some unit tests for methods which (indirectly) write something to a database.
Here's a small example of the classes structure:

```
class SomePersistenceClass
{
    public void Persist(object value, string type)
    {
        if (type.Equals("Numeric"))
        {
            PersistNumeric( (int)value );
        }
    }

    private void PersistNumeric(int number)
    {
        //Some Calculations and Creation of DBObject
        number++;
        var dbObject = new DatabaseObject {DbObjectData = new DatabaseObjectData {Number = number, Creator = "John Doe"}};
        PersistImpl(dbObject);
    }

    private void PersistImpl(IDatabaseObject dbObject)
    {
        try
        {
            dbObject.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //ErrorHandling
            throw;
        }
    }
}

interface IDatabaseObject
{
    DatabaseObjectData DbObjectData { get; set; }
    void Save();
}

class DatabaseObject : IDatabaseObject
{
    public DatabaseObjectData DbObjectData { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        //Save to Database;
    }
}

class DatabaseObjectData
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do now, is test the public persist method. The problem here is, that my DatabaseObject will save the data to an database. It would be easy to mock the DatabaseObject's save method, but I'm not sure what's the best way to inject the mocked object (as you can see, I don't have any knowledge of the DatabaseObject in my public method) into the PersistImpl method. One thougt was to pull up the DatabaseObject creation to the public method.
So something like this:

```
    public void Persist(object value, string type, IDatabaseObject dbObject)
    {
        if (type.Equals("Numeric"))
        {
            PersistNumeric( (int)value, dbObject );
        }
    }

    private void PersistNumeric(int number, IDatabaseObject dbObject)
    {
        //Some Calculations and Creation of DBObject
        number++;
        dbObject.DbObjectData.Number = number;
        dbObject.DbObjectData.Creator = "John Doe";
        PersistImpl(dbObject);
    }
```

But I'm quite unhappy with this soultion. I would need to create the database object outside the persistence class.

Is there are good way to solve such a problem? I definitly have to remove the database access within my unit tests.

Comment: Why not just inject a mock IDatabaseObject in the constructor of SomePersistenceClass?

Comment: That's something I'm thinking about right now. The problem is, I can't use the same DatabaseObject and just replace the data. There are database objects which have states, so I need a own DatabaseObject for every object I want to save.

Comment: fair enough, but all the same, wow. That sounds like a very strange design :) In that case though the factory pattern below is for sure what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is to delegate the construction of the `DatabaseObject` objects to a factory class:

```
interface IDatabaseObjectFactory
{
    IDatabaseObject Create(DatabaseObjectData data);
}

class DatabaseObjectFactory : IDatabaseObjectFactory
{
    public IDatabaseObject Create(DatabaseObjectData data)
    {
        return new DatabaseObject {DbObjectData = data };
    }
}

class SomePersistenceClass
{
    readonly IDatabaseObjectFactory _factory;

    public SomePersistenceClass()
    {
        _factory = new DatabaseObjectFactory();
    }

    public SomePersistenceClass(IDatabaseObjectFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Persist(object value, string type) { /* ... */ }
    private void PersistImpl(IDatabaseObject dbObject) { /* ... */ }

    private void PersistNumeric(int number)
    {
        //Some Calculations and Creation of DBObject
        number++;
        var dbObject = _factory.Create(new DatabaseObjectData {Number = number, Creator = "John Doe"});
        PersistImpl(dbObject);
    }

}
```

Now, if you test your class, you can pass in a `FakeDatabaseObjectFactory` that returns a `FakeDatabaseObject` that will not access your database.

(However, I find the way you handle database access with the `DatabaseObject` class a little bit... strange; but that's another topic).

Comment: This seems to be a good idea to handle the problem. I agree, that the DatabaseObject class is kinda strange, but I'm forced to use it.